# Numpy: vectorized operations to create a 3D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am learning Python and would like to find an efficient way to solve this problem using `Numpy`.

I currently have a `4x8` array containing random integers:

```
import numpy as np

n = 3
k = np.random.randint(n, size = (4,8))
```

Each number represents a color defined by its `RGB` value in a `nx3` array:

```
colors = np.array([[0  , 0  , 0  ],
                   [0  , 100, 255],
                   [255, 100, 0  ]])
```

I would like to use these numbers to create a new `4x8x3` array where the first two dimensions represent pixels locations, and the third dimension the color of each pixel. This could be thought of as number painting. For example, if `k[3,4] = 2`, then `myArray[3,4,:] = [255 100   0]`.

I am getting familiar with `Numpy` tools, but I am unsure of what I should be looking for exactly. Since the array `k` will eventually be much larger (I'm thinking ~`640x480`) and contain more than `n = 3` non-random colors, I would like to use vectorized operations in order to speed up the process (and learn a bit more about them). Is this the most efficient way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, all you need to do is index into `colors` with `k`:

```
>>> k = np.random.randint(n, size = (2,4))
>>> out = colors[k]
>>> out
array([[[  0, 100, 255],
        [255, 100,   0],
        [255, 100,   0],
        [255, 100,   0]],

       [[  0, 100, 255],
        [  0, 100, 255],
        [255, 100,   0],
        [255, 100,   0]]])
>>> out.shape
(2, 4, 3)
>>> all((out[i]==colors[c]).all() for i,c in np.ndenumerate(k))
True
```

Comment: You understood correctly, and this is simpler than I expected. Thanks!

Comment: To add to the answer, this kind of indexing is called [Advanced Indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) as opposed to basic slicing. In this case, advanced indexing is triggered because `k` is a `ndarray`.